# converting binary/octect file into excel file

Tags: python, excel, binary

I have been trying to convert the given file into excel file, but could not able to do.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/doljueyt2h9cjy0/College_Data?dl=0

Comment: can you share your code. what you have tried so far?

Comment: That's just a CSV file and there are many examples on the net for converting CSV to excel, including just importing it in excel itself.